# How to communicate with a Linux kernel module from user space without littering /dev with new nodes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What are the ways to communicate with a kernel module from user space? By communication i mean sending information and commands between the kernel module and a user space process.

I currently know of two way:

1. open/close/read/write/ioctl on published device node.
2. read/write on exported and hooked /proc file.

More specifically, can someone advice the best way to communicate with a kernel module that does not actually drives any hardware and therefore should not be littering /dev with stub nodes that exists solely for ioctl calls? I mostly need to check its various status variables and send it a block of data with a request type tag and see if the request succeeded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Netlink sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) are designed for that kind of requirements, too...

Also see

- man 7 netlink
- [libnl - Netlink library](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/)
- [The libnl Archives](http://bombadil.infradead.org/pipermail/libnl/)

Answer (score 9):

There's also the /sys filesystem (sysfs):

> Sysfs exports information about
>   devices and drivers from the kernel
>   device model to userspace, and is also
>   used for configuration.

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs))

Answer (score 3):

You could also read/write from /dev device nodes.

IMHO, /dev is already littered with stuff and adding your own nodes there isn't a big issue. Don't forget that you can have lots of ioctl codes for a single device node, and the ioctl paramters are passed by reference so can be as big as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Third one is add a new syscall, but the two you have written are the preferred ones, I think. I've found this document that might help, but I still think this option is unadvised: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/CMSC421/fall02/burt/projects/howto_add_systemcall.html

Another acceptable option might be sharing memory.

Comment: I know about replacing a syscall by patching the table, but how do i add a new one?

Comment: I think I read about that in Linux Device Drivers book once, let me take a look...

Comment: Adding new syscalls is strongly discouraged by kernel developers.  In newer kernels they have deliberately made it more difficult.

Comment: @Eric yes, that's the idea I had... I just wanted to show that the option was still there, but remarking that the other options are better.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Shared Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760479/mmap-kernel-buffer-to-user-space/10770582#10770582) and [IOCTL](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com.tr/2012/12/implementing-ioctl-call-for-kernel.html)

Answer (score 0):

**debugfs** is another good possibility for APIs that are less stable than sysfs, but the API is basically the same. Here is a [minimal runnable example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/91583552ba2c2d547c8577ac888ab9f851642b25/kernel_module/debugfs.c).

**configfs** is another one. It allows easy dynamic creation of kernel objects from userspace through the filesystem: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/configfs/configfs.txt

In any case, you will have to dirty *some* namespace... a filesystem entry in case of sysfs and debugfs. Just choose your poison.

Also, `udev` rules make `/dev` very similar to sysfs and debugfs: [How to create a device in /dev automatically upon loading of the kernel module for a device driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697300/how-to-create-a-device-in-dev-automatically-upon-loading-of-the-kernel-module-f)