# How to create a device in /dev automatically upon loading of the kernel module for a device driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am attempting to develop Linux device drivers and as my first attempt I am trying to develop a char device driver that has the following file options,

```
struct file_operations fops{  
.open=open_fun,  
.release=release_fun,  
.write=write_fun,  
.read=read_fun,  
};
```

When I load the driver using `insmod`, I see that `/proc/devices` lists the driver under char devices but I can't find it in `/dev`. A Google search suggested use of `mknod` to create a device in `/dev` and associate it with the driver's major and minor. However, an attempt to do so resulted in "Permission denied" error even when done as a super user.

What should I do to make the device appear in `/dev` when the kernel module is loaded? I tried both the older (`register_chrdev`) and the newer version (`cdev_init & cdev_add`) of registering the device but none of them works.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/create-a-device-node-in-code/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a device node from the init\_module code of a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/how-to-create-a-device-node-from-the-init-module-code-of-a-linux-kernel-module)

Answer (score 9):

- Include the  header file **linux/device.h** and **linux/kdev_t.h**
- static struct class c_dev;
- static struct dev_t dev;

**Add the below API 's inside __init fuction of the driver**

- cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE ,"x");

where x - Name to be displayed inside /sys/class/ when driver is loaded.

- Use device_create () kernel api with device_create(cl, NULL, dev, NULL, "d");

where d - device file to be created under /dev.

where dev is variable for the first device number that is initialized during the usage of **alloc_chrdev_region** API for dynamic allocation of major number for the driver

For Further reference please go through the link http://opensourceforu.com/2011/04/character-device-files-creation-operations/

Answer (score 3):

You may have to [create some udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to tell the system what device node(s) you need it to create.

Answer (score 3):

I could see entries within `/dev` after creating node by running following command at console.

> sudo mknod -m 0666 /dev/msio c 22 0

The user was not root, so I had to use sudo. My entry name was `msio`, a character device with major and minor number 22, 0 respectively.

I will let you know if this can be achieved programatically.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create a device node programmatically. You can use `class_create()` and `device_create` for that. Udev system mentioned by @duskwuff will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks. That helps a lot. Thanks everybody else.

Comment: according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt character device with major number 22, minor number 0 is taken for Digiboard serial card, First port.

Answer (score 2):

CONFIG_DEVTMPFS is quite nice if you can use that with your distro.  You can have the kernel automount that for you at boot (CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT) or mount it manually (mount -t devtmpfs none /dev).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create the device file in `/dev`

- Manually creation of a device file using `mknod`
  `$ mknod -m <permission> <name> <device_type> <major> <minor>` 
  here 
  **name** is the name of device driver,
  **device_type** is the type of the device (b-> block devices , c-> char devices),
   **major & minor** are the device numbers,
   **permission** is optional you can change it after creation, by using `chmod`.
- Dynamic creation using .

```
dev_t dev=0;
static struct class *devicefileClass;
deviceFileClass=class_create(THIS_MODULE,"device_name");
device_create( deviceFileClass , NULL , dev ,"device_name")
```

**NOTE** class_create , device_create  function call should be in your `__init` function.
and include `,`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use :
sudo mknod /dev/devicename c 81 0

It creates device file in /dev but you have to give it read/write permission. to do so,

sudo chmod 777 /dev/devicename

Done !!!