# how to create a /dev/entry after doing an insmod of a module

Tags: linux-device-driver, insmod

I have been provided a Linux kernel module with these instructions: insmod . Then determine the major number and create a /dev entry.
I was able to successfully install  as is evident from the dmesg file. However, I do not know how to determine the device number. Any help appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a device in /dev automatically upon loading of the kernel module for a device driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697300/how-to-create-a-device-in-dev-automatically-upon-loading-of-the-kernel-module-f)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know the name of a device you are talking about. You can retrieve the major number from `/proc/devices`. Here is an extract from this file:

> Character devices:
>    1 mem
>   <...>
>   216 rfcomm
>   226 drm
>   252 hidraw
>   253 bsg
>   254 rtc
>
> Block devices:
>   259 blkext
>    8 sd
>    9 md
>   <...>

Look for the name of your device there. The major number is on the same line, just before the name.

A sidenote.
I would also recommend looking at "Linux Driver Development" book (http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), esp. chapters 1-3. The device numbers and many other useful things are explained there. Although some parts of the book are a bit out-of-date now, it is still very useful.
End of a sidenote.